# what is the use of org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am not sure what this means, I see it in my .classpath

Answer (score 12):

It is a way to reference standard Java classes that come from various jars in your JRE install without hardcodding paths to those locations. The placeholder is resolved to the various actual jars at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

The first answer is basically correct.  Anytime in a .classpath file you see a kind="con" tag, it means that the entry is pointing to a "container" which is an eclipse plugin that extends the extension point for cp containers.  The net effect here is as described before, that the Eclipse JDT will splat all of the appropriate runtime JRE jars.  I make the wider point because you will see Eclipse PDE, M2Eclipse, Eclipse WTP, etc... provide their own classpath containers which will provide their own sets of jars.